# Differing response from HTTParty from IRB and file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, irb, httparty

I got this simple code in a file to test an API Flight service using HTTParty gem

```
require 'httparty'

body = {
    "apiKey": 'xxx',
    "country": 'IN',
    "currency": 'INR',
    "locale": 'en-GB',
    "originplace": 'DEL',
    "destinationplace": 'BLR',
    "outboundDate": '2016-10-14',
    "adults": 1,
    "locationschema": 'Iata'
}
headers = { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}

@response = HTTParty.post("http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/", :body => body,:headers => headers)
puts @response
puts "Response code #{@response.code}"
puts "Reponse header #{@response.headers['location']}"
@sessionKey = @response.headers['location']

sleep 1

@poll = HTTParty.get(@sessionKey.to_s, query: {apiKey: "xxx"})
puts @poll
puts "Polling #{@poll.parsed_response}"
```

If I save this in a file like `api.rb` and run it from a terminal, except for `@response`, no output is shown for the `@poll` object in the terminal. It's just blank. And the blank line is there.

BUT

In `IRB` if I type this code line-by-line I get a response for the `@poll` object.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Could it be because of delay?  Does it work if you change `sleep 1` to, say, `sleep 10` ?

Comment: Just tried. Still doesn't. Actually if you can, check here to generate an API key - http://portal.business.skyscanner.net/en-gb/accounts/dashboard/. Select the Travel API in the Dashboard.

Comment: Can you inspect `@session_key` ? How does it differ between the automated and manual process?

Comment: It returns as a `String`

Comment: I mean the content... how does it differ?

Comment: There is no difference.